# How to create two instances of same java class running in same process?

Tags: java, processbuilder, multiple-instances

I am learning Java Process and I am trying to create two instances of same java class running in same process which is a requirement.

```
class Chat {
    public void getMessage() { * * * some implementation
    }
}

class ProcessMain {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Chat c1 = new Chat();
         Chat c2 = new Chat();
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(c1); * * * * here is where I am stuck.
         Two instances of same class should run in same process
     }
 }
```

Can anyone give me a lead?

Comment: `c1` and `c2` are already running in the same process. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Instance 1 should send message to instance 2. The instance 2 should receive the message and reply to the instance 1 with the received message. This should run in same process.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is used to create new processes on the system. The running Java application is already a single process.

Comment: Ok.  Ok. Thanks for your lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Java will run the main class in a single process, on the same [thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). If you want to have two classes communicate with one another you can pass [c1 into a method inside of c2](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-passing-object-as-parameter-to-method/) and alter c1 that way.